# xamarin android: view pager fragment swipe HOW TO

Tags: listview, android-fragments, xamarin, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

i work with visual studio 2015 and xamarin.
i have a litle experience with xamarin android.

what i need is to do that : 
realize an application with 3 screens where it's possible to swipe between these screens :
1) report screen
2) Main screen
3) detail screen

ok, i've realize an app with a viewPager and these three fragment => all works actually .. :)

But the goal has change, now i must to load in first the main screen who contains a list.
Ok i've do that with 
viewPager.SetCurrentItem(1, true);

```
viewPager.SetCurrentItem(1, true);
```

and all works and i can swipe to Main or report or detail

But my last problem it's this , i need when i click on the list view to load the detail fragment .. but i can't !!!!

i've try some manipulation with fragmentManager.Replace but all my test is crashing !

```
// inside listview item click
DetailFragment detail = new DetailFragment();

            //
            Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            ft.Replace(Resource.Layout.MainLayout, detail);

            //
            ft.AddToBackStack(null);
            ft.Commit();
```

I'm completly lost, sorry for my english it's too bad !

i hope your're understand my problem, 3 fragments inside a viewPager, load the second fragment when app start. Click on list item load detail fragment ...

If some people have any idea ?

thanks for your time and ALL your knowledge that's really nice to share it

Comment: If your app crashes, please include stack traces and exception messages.

Comment: Hello cheesebaron i have this message when i run my app, click on a item in the list view => Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f030003 (SwipeWithoutTab.SwipeWithoutTab:layout/MainLayout) for fragment DetailFragment{41678a78 #2 id=0x7f030003}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your replace transaction, you are trying to replace an ID which is not in the current layout.

You are attempting to replace `Resource.Layout.MainLayout`. The replace transaction expects an ID of a view currently in your view hierarchy.

EDIT:

It is not clear how you are showing your ViewPager to begin with. Let us assume it is inflated in a Fragment on its own. That Fragment in turn is shown in `Resource.Id.content`, which is the placeholder you are using to show your Fragments in.

`Resource.Id.content` is in the layout inflated in your `Activity`, where you set up your Fragment with your ViewPager. They layout could simply be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The FrameLayout is what you are effectively replacing when you are doing your Transaction. What you are replacing, must be a part of the layout. You cannot just say you want to replace the entire layout as it is not a visible ID.

Comment: Thanks for your time but it's not really clear sorry ...i'm not new with activity but fragment is new for me ...The MainLayout it's the layout of the fragment that i'm trying to replace ... I need to replace the main fragment by the detail fragment ... Have you got any sample ? thanks cheesebaron

Comment: Hello cheesbaron, hm hm i'm think we're not too far from the solution ...

Comment: Hello cheesbaron, hm hm i'm think we're not too far from the solution ... If i understand the frameLayout is a container WHERE i must to use for to place or replace the fragment ...Ok on my mainLayout where i have my list view i have place a framelayout and INSIDE this frameLayout i have place my listview => Now if i run my app and click on a item in the listview the detail fragment IS WELL loaded ..BUT the list view is still there ! I think there is something that i can't understand SORRY i try to use fragment since this monday ..Thanks

Comment: NEWS => if i delete my view pager and add your frameLayout that's work fine :) But where i must to put my view pager ...? thanks for all guy

Comment: In a Fragment, which you use a transaction to show in the FrameLayout